# C# Datagrid link to textbox error

Tags: c#, winforms, datagrid, textbox

I am having problem with code block below, My purpose with the code block to link selected row's datas on datagrid to textboxes belong. I added the code below to Datagridview content.

Mostly it works but in first time when you click cell on datagrid for "name" and "surname" it dosen't link/transfer datas to text box. However other column after "surname" are works very well. As well when the program is running and after a couple click on "name" and "surname" columns then it's  transfer/link.

Is there any idea why thats happening or how can i edit code?

```
private void dgvEkip_CellContentClick(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
        {
            if(e.RowIndex >= 0)
            {
                DataGridViewRow row = this.dgvEkip.Rows[e.RowIndex];
                txtEkipIsim.Text = row.Cells["Isim"].Value.ToString();                  //cell for "name"
                txtEkipSoyisim.Text = row.Cells["Soyisim"].Value.ToString();            //cell for "surname"
                dtpEkipDogum.Text = row.Cells["DogumTarihi"].Value.ToString();
                txtEkipTelefon.Text = row.Cells["Telefon"].Value.ToString();
                txtEkipEposta.Text = row.Cells["ePosta"].Value.ToString();
                cbEkipSehir.Text = row.Cells["Sehir"].Value.ToString();
                txtEkipAdres.Text = row.Cells["Adres"].Value.ToString();
                dtpEkipKayitTarihi.Text = row.Cells["KayitTarihi"].Value.ToString();
            }
        }
```

As well here is an screenshot:

[sample](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4zJoh.png)

thanks a lot, Nuri.

Comment: what happens when you step through it? Have you tried printing out the value in the console window inside of Visual Studio (i.e. `Debug.Print(row.Cells["Isim"].Value.ToString())`?

Comment: I don't uderstand why it doesn't work, However, you may set the DataGridView.SelectionMode to FullRowSelect and use the RowEnter event (don't forget do call this event once after filling the DataGridView).

Comment: try to subscribing other event like RowSelected, RowHightlighted, CellFocused

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I Think you shound show message EXception in here. May be I can support for you :D
And i see type tool you use not textbox "dtpEkipDogum", you can check it